# easiest way to peel/skin a tongue?

Tags: peeling, skin, offal

So I've boiled a couple lamb tongues -- as per [this recipe](http://www.food24.com/Recipes/Tender-lamb-tongue-20091103) -- and have them cool enough to handle, however I'm having difficulty peeling the skin/film off them with just my fingers alone.

Is there some trick to doing this?

Comment: Yeah, after a ton of more googling, I'm starting to get the impression that a sign of an under-cooked tongue is one which is decidedly hard to peel...

Answer (score 2):

You'll need a lot longer than 20 minutes that the recipe suggests.  For cow tongue, we usually let them sit in a crock-pot for about 4hrs.  My guess for lamb tongue is about 90 minutes on low simmer.

The skin tends come loose from the muscle underneath when done. The best trick I've found is to cut the skin down the center of the tongue (lengthwise). Use a sharp knife and try not to cut too much of the muscle or some of the meat will peel with the skin.

You can then peel off the skin easily ending up in two sheets (one for each side). Wearing latex or dishwashing gloves helps buffer some of the heat, but as long as they are above room temperature the peeling should go fine and easy.

Comment: I'll give this a go, and if it works give you the "check mark". Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I learned from Iranian ladies in Iran, clean the tongue first, boil it on a low heat for 60 minutes at low altitude. Longer time needed at High altitude. When the outer skin shows signs of separating from the muscle, then drench the tongue in cold water for 10/15 minutes. The skin will separate from the muscle easily.
This method is also used in Lebanon.,